# How long is the redemption period on a domain?

Tags: domain-registration

There is a domain that I would like to buy that has a status as follows:
Registry Status: redemptionPeriod

I presume this means the current owner has a grace period during which they can repurchase the domain but it is not available on the open market.

How long is this period?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends who the domain is registered with. ICANN who oversee domain registration say

> 3.7.5 Registrar shall register Registered Names to Registered Name Holders only for fixed periods. 
>   http://www.icann.org/en/registrars/ra-agreement-17may01.htm#3

but don't specify the period.

Nominet, who oversee most .uk domains, allow [83 days](http://www.nominet.org.uk/registrants/maintain/renew/) which includes repeated reminders.

With Network Solutions:

> Typically, we provide a 35-day grace period during which the current
>   holder can still renew it for the standard renewal fee.

http://www.networksolutions.com/domain-name-registration/pending.jsp

See who the domain is registered with (various "whois" services are available) and then see what the registrar's policy is.

Comment: Grace period is longer than I thought it would be, that's very generous imo...

Answer (score 9):

Here is the of generic Top Level Domain life cycle from [ICANN](http://www.icann.org/en/resources/registrars/gtld-lifecycle): [image: gTLD lifecycle]
So, it is typically 30 + 5 days. However as they state:

> Some registrar activity post-expiration may not be reflected in the life cycle chart above.

Thus, I guess, it's not strictly defined.