# whois shows status "pending delete"

Tags: domains

I want to buy a domain that is in a status pendingDelete.

who.is shows:

```
Registrar: NAMEKING.COM, INC.
Whois Server: whois.nameking.com
Referral URL: http://www.nameking.com
Status: pendingDelete

Expiration Date: 2011-10-08
Creation Date: 2003-10-08
Last Update Date: 2011-12-08

Name Servers:
    ns1.dsredirection.com
    ns2.dsredirection.com

Information Updated: Wed, 14 Dec 2011 18:14:18 UTC
```

Can I know why this domain isn't expired yet (considering its expiration date)?

Consider that I have actived a backorder from godaddy too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a varying amount of time after a domain expires while it still can be renewed by the original owner.
[How long is the redemption period on a domain?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19400/how-long-is-the-redemption-period-on-a-domain)

[when does a domain name really expire before someone else can register it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20309/when-does-a-domain-name-really-expire-before-someone-else-can-register-it)

So you may have to wait a while longer.

Here's what Godaddy say about [backordering](https://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/jump_pages/BackorderExplanation.asp):

> Backorder this name and we will ATTEMPT to grab and register it on
>   your behalf, if and when it expires and becomes available.

So a) you'll have to wait a while and b) they don't guarantee they'll get it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: so basically it's completed useless that i have bought backorder from godaddy considering this domain is from nameking.com ?

Comment: I've updated the question to answer that.

Comment: oh gosh :( now it says it's of anotehr registrar :( barginregister.com and it's not in pendingDelete anymore