# Do the registrars that provide gTLDs like .xyz have an obligation to allow me to renew each year?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

This probably varies by gTLD provider, but if I buy a domain from a registrar, are they required to let me renew?

Related question: [What happens if a gTLD fails to pay ICANN in time?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/89673/what-happens-if-a-gtld-fails-to-pay-icann-in-time)

Comment: I guess it would depend upon their point of view. However, from a business standpoint, it would not make sense to not allow you to renew unless there is a really really really good reason. This is simple to understand. It is far easier to sell a product to someone who is already using it. As well, if taking back domain names for whatever reason is a standard practice, then no-one would buy for fear that the domain name they are expecting to depend upon would be taken away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you buy a domain name you own that domain name for the duration of the agreed period, whether it be a 1 year, 2 year, etc domain registration. During that time only you are allowed to use the domain name or make changes to the underlying details of the domain name.

When it comes time to renewing the domain, while there is strictly speaking no requirement to allow the renewal, there is a requirement to allow domain transfers to another registrar, as such practically every registrar out there lets the domain owner renew before expire. If your domain has expired then how long after the expire until it can be bought by someone else depends on the gTLD in question. Some have a 30 day grace period, others it is straight away, and listing each one is beyond the scope of this question.

Basically it is something that, while unwritten, has become a right due to the supporting right of transfer which would negate any effort by a registrar to prevent you from renewing your own domain name. Most gTLD's also have dispute processes, which vary from gTLD to gTLD. If you encounter this sort of issue and wish to raise it as a dispute check the registry for the gTLD you are using and find out what their disputes process is and raise a dispute.

Sources:

- [Can a registrar ransom a domain name which has become popular?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25387/can-a-registrar-ransom-a-domain-name-which-has-become-popular)
- https://au.godaddy.com/help/can-i-renew-my-domain-name-after-it-expires-609
- https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/name-holder-faqs-2012-02-25-en